# jQuery addClass causes no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class where I want to change a single attribute with a javascript function.

```
.msg_archivedropdown:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    left:-7px;
    top:0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid #FFFFFF; 
}
```

I'm already using jQuery, so I've tried to do it with `addClass`:

```
function colorbubble(){
    $("archivedropdown before").addClass("msg_archivedropdownhover before");
}
```

The added class looks like this, only the border color changes:

```
.msg_archivedropdownhover:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    left:-7px;
    top:0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid #DFDFDF;
}
```

Sadly, there's nothing changing. I've tried various kind of ways so far. I've tried to do it with:

```
$('.msg_archivedropdown before').css('border-right-color','#DFDFDF;');
```

Which got me nowhere and I also tried to loop through a `getElementsbyClass` which did not work either. I´m doing something wrong. Can someone please give me a hint? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

It's a speech-bubble where I made a triangle in the `.msg_archivedropdown:before`-class. On a `mouseover` event I want to change the color of the triangle as well. So I only want to change the color of the `.msg_archivedropdown:before` class.

Comment: I thinks that the **;** is the problem, remove it from `css('border-right-color','#DFDFDF;');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jquery for a trivial case like this. You could just use `:hover` pseudo-class instead.

```css
.msg_archivedropdown {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    position: relative;
}

.msg_archivedropdown::before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    left:-7px;
    top:0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid #FFFFFF; 
}

.msg_archivedropdown:hover::before {
    border-right:7px solid #DFDFDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg_archivedropdown"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the replays. That did the job in the most easiest way.

Comment: Glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the pseudo `:before` element in Jquery and you can't do it use  `$('.msg_archivedropdown:before')`

so your alternative is to add class with pseudo element as `msg_archivedropdown` and in function `toggleClass` then the new class apply on DOM with the `boreder-color`

Do it as below:

```js
function colorbubble(){
    $('.msg_archivedropdown').toggleClass('beforeClass');
}
```

```css
.msg_archivedropdown:before,.beforeClass:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    left:3px;
    top:0px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid #FFFFFF; 
     background: red
}
.beforeClass:before{
 border-right-color:blue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="msg_archivedropdown">show div</div>
<button onclick="colorbubble()">change</button>
```

Comment: Ho..I did not see your edit about `hover` best way in this case to use css `:hover` as @VilleKoo answer